# Gallery app crashes at startup

Tags: 7.0-nougat, gallery

Currently, I am facing a very weird problem with the default gallery app in my Android 7.0 OS. My device's model is ***Micromax Bharat 3 Q437***. The crash is occurring randomly-- before a day it was working absolutely fine. I did no special task on my phone which can cause the problem. The package name of the app is `com.android.gallery3d`.

Here is the output of `adb logcat *:E -e "gallery"` command:

```
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.android.gallery3d, PID: 29467
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.mediatek.galleryfeature.gif.GifMember.isMatching(GifMember.java:30)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.mediatek.galleryframework.base.MediaCenter.getMember(MediaCenter.java:109)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.mediatek.galleryframework.base.MediaCenter.getItem(MediaCenter.java:27)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.data.LocalImage.updateMediaData(LocalImage.java:592)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.data.LocalImage.<init>(LocalImage.java:163)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.data.LocalAlbum.loadOrUpdateItem(LocalAlbum.java:196)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.data.LocalAlbum.getMediaItem(LocalAlbum.java:168)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.data.LocalMergeAlbum$FetchCache.getItem(LocalMergeAlbum.java:285)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.data.LocalMergeAlbum.getMediaItem(LocalMergeAlbum.java:168)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.data.MediaSet.getCoverMediaItem(MediaSet.java:85)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.data.LocalMergeAlbum.getCoverMediaItem(LocalMergeAlbum.java:334)
03-06 14:13:24.096 29467 29482 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.gallery3d.app.AlbumSetDataLoader$ReloadTask.run(AlbumSetDataLoader.java:449)
```

What can be the possible cause for this and how to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Did you check on Play store for updates to that app?

Comment: Since I bought the phone about 2 years ago, there are no updates to that app.

Comment: The app `com.android.gallery3d` is not available in Play Store. Based on the exception it seems like your device has a MediaTek CPU/GPU and the error happens in a Mediatek helper library. Therefore I see only two possibilities: Use a different gallery app or try to remove the GIF file that causes the problem. If you are not sure what GIF file causes the problem move them all to a different folder (do this on-device, don't use a PC for that! some devices have a bug that deletes the file if you move it via PC).

Comment: Yes, my device has MediaTek CPU

Comment: I could not find any GIF files in my phone's storage.